# Edit and Delete does not work in CRUD with Primefaces

Tags: hibernate

I have a table which put together a CRUD, but it works only inserting records, but not editing and deleting them.

I've been reviewing the code many times, but can not find the explanation, as in these cases, the failure may be silly, but I'm so frustrated and asked to help you.

The table is called "Locations" and has the following structure:
[image]

The peculiarity of it is that the column called idlocalidadpadre may or may not have references to idlocalidad column (this is because they can be grouped).

The DAO code is as follows:

```
package daosimplementaciones;

import daos.LocalidadesDao;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import pojos.Localidades;
import utiles.HibernateUtil;


public class LocalidadesDaoImp implements LocalidadesDao {

@Override
public void registrar(Localidades localidad) {
    Session sesion = null;
    try {
        sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        sesion.beginTransaction();
        sesion.save(localidad);
        sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        if (sesion != null) {
            sesion.close();
        }
    }
}

**@Override
public void modificar(Localidades localidad) {
    Session sesion = null;
    try {
        sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        sesion.beginTransaction();
        sesion.update(localidad);
        sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        if (sesion != null) {
            sesion.close();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void eliminar(Localidades localidad) {
    Session sesion = null;
    try {
        sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        sesion.beginTransaction();
        sesion.delete(localidad);
        sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        if (sesion != null) {
            sesion.close();
        }
    }
}**

@Override
public List<Localidades> verLocalidades() {
    List<Localidades> listaLocalidades = null;
    Session sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaccion = sesion.beginTransaction();

    String hql = "FROM Localidades";
    //String hql = "SELECT l.idlocalidad, l.descripcion, l.esrural, l.iddistrito, l1.Descripcion FROM localidades l LEFT OUTER JOIN localidades l1 ON l.`idlocalidadpadre` = l1.`idlocalidad`";

    try {
        listaLocalidades = sesion.createQuery(hql).list();
        transaccion.commit();
        //sesion.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaccion.rollback();
    }finally{
        if(sesion != null){
            //sesion.close();
        }
    }

    return listaLocalidades;
}

@Override
public Localidades verLocalidad(int idLocalidad){
    Query consulta = null;
    Session sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try{
    String hql = "FROM Localidades WHERE IdLocalidad=:idLocalidad";
    consulta = sesion.createQuery(hql);
    consulta.setParameter("idLocalidad", idLocalidad);
    sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    sesion.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
    }finally{
        if(sesion != null){
            sesion.close();
        }
    }

    return (Localidades) consulta.uniqueResult();
}

@Override
public String verNombreLocalidadPadre(Integer idLocalidadPadre) {
    Integer idLocParametro;
    idLocParametro = idLocalidadPadre;
    if(idLocParametro == null){
        idLocParametro = 0;
    }
    Query consulta = null;
    Session sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    sesion.getTransaction().begin();

    try{
        String hql = "SELECT descripcion FROM Localidades WHERE IdLocalidad=:idLoc";
        consulta = sesion.createQuery(hql);
        consulta.setParameter("idLoc", idLocParametro);
        sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    //sesion.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
    }finally{
        if(sesion != null){
            //sesion.close();
        }
    }

    try{
        String resultado = (String) consulta.uniqueResult();
        return resultado;
    }catch(NullPointerException npe){
        return "";
    }

    //return (String) consulta.uniqueResult();
}
```

}

The method "verNombreLocalidadPadre" is used so as not to see the location code of idlocalidadpadre column, but its description in sight.

Bean driver code is as follows:

```
package beans;

import daos.LocalidadesDao;
import daosimplementaciones.LocalidadesDaoImp;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import pojos.Localidades;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class LocalidadesBean implements Serializable {

private List<Localidades> listaLocalidades;
private Localidades localidad;
/**
 * Creates a new instance of LocalidadesBean
 */
public LocalidadesBean() {
    localidad = new Localidades();
}

public List<Localidades> getListaLocalidades() {
    LocalidadesDao lDao = new LocalidadesDaoImp();
    listaLocalidades = lDao.verLocalidades();
    return listaLocalidades;
}

public void setListaLocalidades(List<Localidades> listaLocalidades) {
    this.listaLocalidades = listaLocalidades;
}

public Localidades getLocalidad() {
    return localidad;
}

public void setLocalidad(Localidades localidad) {
    this.localidad = localidad;
}

//A partir de acá tenemos los métodos que vamos a utilizar
public void prepararNuevaLocalidad(){
    localidad = new Localidades();
}

public void nuevaLocalidad(){
    LocalidadesDao lDao = new LocalidadesDaoImp();
    lDao.registrar(localidad);
    this.localidad = new Localidades();
}

public String nombreDeLocalidadPadre(int idLocalidadPadre){
    LocalidadesDao lDao = new LocalidadesDaoImp();
    return lDao.verNombreLocalidadPadre(idLocalidadPadre);
}

**public void modificarLocalidad(){
    LocalidadesDao lDao = new LocalidadesDaoImp();
    lDao.modificar(localidad);
    localidad = new Localidades();
}

public void eliminarLocalidad(){
    LocalidadesDao lDao = new LocalidadesDaoImp();
    lDao.eliminar(localidad);
    localidad = new Localidades();
}**
```

}

And finally, the view code is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<body>

<ui:composition template="./../../plantilla/plantilla.xhtml">

   <ui:define name="content">
        <h2>Detalle de Localidades</h2>

        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Nueva Localidad" actionListener="#{localidadesBean.prepararNuevaLocalidad()}" oncomplete="PF('dialogoNuevaLocalidad').show();" update=":formNuevaLocalidad"/>
        </h:form>

        <h:form id="formMostrarLocalidades">

            <p:dataTable id="tablaLocalidades" var="loc" value="#{localidadesBean.listaLocalidades}" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" emptyMessage="No hay datos de Localidades">

                <p:column headerText="Número de Localidad">
                    <h:outputText value="#{loc.idlocalidad}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Nombre de Localidad">
                    <h:outputText value="#{loc.descripcion}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="¿Es Rural?">
                    <!--<h:outputText value="#{loc.esrural}"/>-->
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="true" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Distrito">
                    <h:outputText value="#{loc.iddistrito}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Agrupada con">
                    <h:outputText value="#{localidadesBean.nombreDeLocalidadPadre(loc.idlocalidadpadre)}"/>
                    <!--<h:outputText value="#{loc.idlocalidadpadre}"/>-->
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Modificar">
                    <p:commandButton value="Modificar" oncomplete="PF('dialogoModificarLocalidad').show();" update=":formModificarLocalidad">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{localidadesBean.localidad}" value="#{loc}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Eliminar">
                    <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" oncomplete="PF('dialogoEliminarLocalidad').show();" update=":formEliminarLocalidad">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{localidadesBean.localidad}" value="#{loc}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </h:form>

        <!-- Formulario para agregar Localidades -->
        <h:form id="formNuevaLocalidad">

            <p:dialog id="dlgNuevaLocalidad" widgetVar="dialogoNuevaLocalidad" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: 0 auto;">

                    <p:outputLabel value="Nombre de Localidad:"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.descripcion}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="¿Es Rural?:"/>
                    <!--<p:inputText value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.esrural}"/>-->
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.esrural}" >
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="No"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Si"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Distrito:"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.iddistrito}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Agrupada con:"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.idlocalidadpadre}" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Localidad de la que depende:" itemValue=""/>
                        <f:selectItems var = "locPadre" value="#{localidadesBean.listaLocalidades}" itemValue ="#{locPadre.idlocalidad}" itemLabel = "#{locPadre.descripcion}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Guardar" actionListener="#{localidadesBean.nuevaLocalidad()}" update=":formMostrarLocalidades:tablaLocalidades" oncomplete="PF('dialogoNuevaLocalidad').hide();"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('dialogoNuevaLocalidad').hide();"/>

            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>

        **<!-- Formulario para Modificar Localidades -->
        <h:form id="formModificarLocalidad">

            <p:dialog id="dlgModificarLocalidad" widgetVar="dialogoModificarLocalidad" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: 0 auto;">

                    <p:outputLabel value="Nombre de Localidad:"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.descripcion}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="¿Es Rural?:"/>
                    <!--<p:inputText value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.esrural}"/>-->
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.esrural}" >
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="No"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Si"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Distrito:"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.iddistrito}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Agrupada con:"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{localidadesBean.localidad.idlocalidadpadre}" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Localidad de la que depende:" itemValue=""/>
                        <f:selectItems var = "locPadre" value="#{localidadesBean.listaLocalidades}" itemValue ="#{locPadre.idlocalidad}" itemLabel = "#{locPadre.descripcion}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Guardar" actionListener="#{localidadesBean.modificarLocalidad()}" update=":formMostrarLocalidades:tablaLocalidades" oncomplete="PF('dialogoModificarLocalidad').hide();"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('dialogoModificarLocalidad').hide();"/>


            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>**

        **<!-- Formulario para Eliminar Localidades -->
        <h:form id="formEliminarLocalidad">

            <p:dialog id="dlgEliminarLocalidad" widgetVar="dialogoEliminarLocalidad" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">

                <h:outputText value="¿Realmente desea eliminar este registro? "/>

                <p:commandButton value="Si" actionListener="#{localidadesBean.eliminarLocalidad()}" update=":formMostrarLocalidades:tablaLocalidades" oncomplete="PF('dialogoEliminarLocalidad').hide();"/>
                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" onclick="PF('dialogoEliminarLocalidad').hide();"/>


            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>**

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</body>
</html>
```

As I said, the creation of new records works perfectly, but editing and erasure.

When I want to do any of these last two operations, no error occurs, but neither carried out any action.

Of course, I appreciate your very kind attention.

Gustavo Echenique

The complete code is here:
https://mega.nz/#F!wdImUCzY!GromEmYACoaJdDheeibMug

Comment: Hi, please, please, please create an [mcve]... see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: and if you create an mcve (preferably one for each failing case), please use english terms in the labels, ids etc... much easier for us (Sorry, besides Dutch, English, German and French, Spanish is not my strongest language)

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, now I added a link to download the project database and to test the complete example.

Comment: Sorry, nobody is going to have a look at that. Or in other words: "What part of 'minimal' was hard to understand?"

Comment: Forgive me really, but since I'm the one with the problem, I find it difficult to discriminate the least, because unfortunately do not know where the fault lies. In addition, the concept of minimum is very broad.

Comment: The concept of minimal is narrowed down al lot…  to complete and verifyable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was in the method "verLocalidades" of the DAO, as it was said logoff and never did.

This caused when a new session, hibernate not record opened, throwing an error that was not showing.

Error code:

```
@Override
public List<Localidades> verLocalidades() {
    List<Localidades> listaLocalidades = null;
    Session sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaccion = sesion.beginTransaction();

    String hql = "FROM Localidades";
    //String hql = "SELECT l.idlocalidad, l.descripcion, l.esrural, l.iddistrito, l1.Descripcion FROM localidades l LEFT OUTER JOIN localidades l1 ON l.`idlocalidadpadre` = l1.`idlocalidad`";

    try {
        listaLocalidades = sesion.createQuery(hql).list();
        transaccion.commit();
        //sesion.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaccion.rollback();
    }finally{
        if(sesion != null){
            //sesion.close();
        }
    }

    return listaLocalidades;
}
```

Removing the comment to logoff, works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry to say but this answer is as usefull as the question: not. Please learn how to create good questions and for that you need to learn how to debug and break down you problem. Do you see no this is largely *hibernate* related.  And errors not being shown is most of the time caused by the developer swallowing the exception